# В мобильной версии ruSO нет запуска сниппетов

Tags: предложение, сниппеты, мобильная-версия

Собственно, если открыть ответ со сниппетом на телефоне, то кнопки Запустить там нет.

Comment: А в en.SO есть кнопка? И речь о мобильной версии сайта или о приложении? Можете дать ссылки на примеры вопросов?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, о сайте. Про приложение я вообще не знал. Английскую версию сейчас проверю.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, на enSO тоже нет.

Comment: приложение имеет ограниченный функционал, но его отрабатывает хорошо. Нет разве что очередей проверок и деталей в профиле пользователя. И перевода интерфейса нет. Но все равно рекомендую.

Comment: А в чем состоит ваше предложение? И к кому оно направлено?

Comment: @Kromster, к разработчикам SO. Добавить запуск сниппетов.